# What's up with my FPS? I have a decent setup

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Here's the thing. I have a decent set-up. 8Gb(s) of RAM, and 4GB(s) of video memory (I think that's the name.) and GTA only uses like 888mb of my video mem. and around 1.3GB(s) RAM. Any reason? Normally, with and without mod menu, its around 30-15 fps

On mod menu I drop down to 4 fps
it does the same thing without it
like say I'm driving down the road
and I'll bug so bad I can take a sip of coffee
and open twitter for a bit before my game comes
back into motion. Sucks.

Before I get out of my house its like 29-31 FPS
but out of it, then it gets messed up.

Comment: Memory isn't the only thing. What kind of CPU? What kind of graphics card?

Comment: Have you updated your video drivers?

Comment: I believe my drivers are updated because I run other games smoothly.

Comment: I have Intel Core I3
21 GBs vram

Comment: A core I3 is not really suited for gaming.

Comment: Nor does it have 21Gb of VRAM.  Nothing in this world has that much except for extremely high end workstation graphics cards.

Comment: Do you want a screenshot of the VRAM? Don't get me wrong I may have had it confused. The name in the box says Virtual Memory

Answer (score 1):

Since gta v needs quite a lot of cpu power, investigate the state of your cpu. Also look out for thermal throttling in your cpu and gpu. Also if you have this pproblem with other openworld games ther might be a problem with your storage. For example if your game is installed o an ssd, keep note that ssd speeds come down dramatically when they're too full. Also open task manager and end all the background tasks you don't need and then try the game.